# Project type for executing JavaScript in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, ide

Is there any IntelliJ IDEA project type that allows me to execute JavaScript, showing the results in the console?

I've been trying *HTML5_Boilerplate*, but it requires to generate the HTML with the embedded script, for instance.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**: IDEA can actually do it by taking advantage of Node, no need for an external browser, as long as IDEA's console can do the trick:

[image]

How can I set this up from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

IDEA itself can't execute Javascript, it can only be executed by browsers/Node.js interpreter. Project type doesn't matter. If you like to be able to run `.js` files with Node.js via **Run** command in right-click menu, you need to make sure that **NodeJS** plugin is installed and enabled. You can install it via **Settings | Plugins**, **Install JetBrains plugin...**

Comment: can't see what you update adds to my answer. It's not 'IDEA console' that does the trick. As I wrote, you can run `.js` files with node.js via *Run* command in right-click menu, but you need to make sure that **NodeJS** plugin is installed and enabled. You can install it via **Settings | Plugins, Install JetBrains plugin...**

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 2020 and NodeJS is bundled, but when I right click on a *.js file I don't see a Run or Debug choice.