# With IntelliJ 2020 Ultimate how can I run any Javascript file with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

**Is there a way (in IntelliJ Ultimate) to run any javascript file with NodeJS?**

I'm basically looking for the Run command to do

```
cd DIRECTORY-OF-FILE
node SELECTED-FILE
```

**I would like Debug command to also work**; And I realize that not every javascript file is formatted to run in nodejs. :-)

I'm looking for functionality that is built-in for Java (to be able to right click and select run or debug a *.java file).

I have a bunch of sample programs and it is a PITA to create a Run/Debug configuration for each simple script.

**What have I done**

I've searched the internet `intellij run JS file in node`
and come up with how to run a single file with NodeJS.  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#debugLocal.  This works ok.

I've searched stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bintellij-idea%5D+run+javascript+file+with+nodejs

And come up with

- [Project type for executing JavaScript in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518869/project-type-for-executing-javascript-in-intellij-idea/49520809#49520809) - This is very similar and if there were an answer, it would likely answer my question.

Comment: In PHPStorm which is almost Intellij in Run -> Edit Configurations you can add a Node.js configuration where you can select a specific .js file. Maybe in Intellij there is a similar option https://imgur.com/a/GTn9KOi or maybe there is a plugin for it

Comment: Is NodeJS plugin enabled? What are the context menu options you get in a JS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Run context menu in the JS file (or the corresponding keyboard shortcut):

[image: Run menu]

Comment: I've found that sometimes the Run and Debug choices do not appear.  I don't know why this happens.  When I stopped and restarted IntelliJ they did appear.  So if they don't appear, try restarting IntelliJ Ultimate. :-)